# Finding infimum/supremum of arbitrary function over interval to compute and plot darboux sums in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am essentially looking to compute and plot the Riemann/Darboux sum of an arbitrary function very similar to this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x : 1/(1+x**2)
a = 0; b = 5; N = 10
n = 10 # Use n*N+1 points to plot the function smoothly

x = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
y = f(x)

X = np.linspace(a,b,n*N+1)
Y = f(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.plot(X,Y,'b')
x_left = x[:-1] # Left endpoints
y_left = y[:-1]
plt.plot(x_left,y_left,'b.',markersize=10)
plt.bar(x_left,y_left,width=(b-a)/N,alpha=0.2,align='edge',edgecolor='b')
plt.title('Left Riemann Sum, N = {}'.format(N))

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(X,Y,'b')
x_mid = (x[:-1] + x[1:])/2 # Midpoints
y_mid = f(x_mid)
plt.plot(x_mid,y_mid,'b.',markersize=10)
plt.bar(x_mid,y_mid,width=(b-a)/N,alpha=0.2,edgecolor='b')
plt.title('Midpoint Riemann Sum, N = {}'.format(N))

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(X,Y,'b')
x_right = x[1:] # Left endpoints
y_right = y[1:]
plt.plot(x_right,y_right,'b.',markersize=10)
plt.bar(x_right,y_right,width=-(b-a)/N,alpha=0.2,align='edge',edgecolor='b')
plt.title('Right Riemann Sum, N = {}'.format(N))

plt.show()

dx = (b-a)/N
x_left = np.linspace(a,b-dx,N)
x_midpoint = np.linspace(dx/2,b - dx/2,N)
x_right = np.linspace(dx,b,N)

print("Partition with",N,"subintervals.")
left_riemann_sum = np.sum(f(x_left) * dx)
print("Left Riemann Sum:",left_riemann_sum)

midpoint_riemann_sum = np.sum(f(x_midpoint) * dx)
print("Midpoint Riemann Sum:",midpoint_riemann_sum)

right_riemann_sum = np.sum(f(x_right) * dx)
print("Right Riemann Sum:",right_riemann_sum)
```

Taken from [HERE](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Epwalls/math-python/integration/riemann-sums/).

However, instead of computing the left, right and middle sums, what I am looking to find is a way to compute the upper and lower darboux sums, that is, **the sum over the infima/suprema of each interval**.

To achieve this I would have to find the infimum/supremum of the function in each interval, but I am at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a matrix containing all the intervals and applying the maximum/minimum a long one axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x : 1/(1+x**2)
a = 0; b = 5; N = 10
n = 10 # Use n*N+1 points to plot the function smoothly

x = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
y = f(x)

X = np.linspace(a,b,n*N+1)
Y = f(X)

plt.plot(X,Y,'b')
# create offset vector with n elements, broadcast is used to enable transpose
dx = np.broadcast_to(np.linspace(0,(b-a)/N,n), (1,n)).T 
# Compute all values for the offset vector (nxN matrix)
F = f(x[:-1]+dx)
y_upper = np.amax(F,0)
y_lower = np.amin(F,0)
print(y_upper)
plt.bar(x[1:],y_upper,width=-(b-a)/N,alpha=0.2,align='edge',edgecolor='b')
plt.bar(x[1:],y_lower,width=-(b-a)/N,alpha=0.2,align='edge',edgecolor='r')
plt.title('Darboux sums, N = {}'.format(N))

plt.show()
```